# Why was I refused a Canadian visit visa?

Tags: canada, visa-refusals, mauritian-citizens

Hi I'm a citizen of Mauritius. I applied to Canada for a temporary visa to see a friend who would give me accommodation for 1 month. To my surprise my visa was refused, for the following reasons:

1. Travel history: I don't understand this statement as I have been to Japan, Malaysia, Australia, Switzerland, France, England, Germany, Italy and Spain.
2. Family ties in Canada and Mauritius: True for Canada as I'm visiting a friend; incorrect for Mauritius, as mentioned in my application that my dad and I live in the same house.
3. Reason for my visit: I said that it was for tourism.
4. Finance: I said that I would bring $2000 for the month, and I would have free accommodation. However, the bank statement which I provided showed more than that amount.
5. Job: I provided a letter from my employer, a international company, in which I'm a senior software engineer.

With all this, I don't understand the refusal. Can I do anything about it?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60991/discussion-on-question-by-jean-guy-zamudio-why-was-i-refused-a-canadian-visit-vi).

Answer (score 4):

Two things:

1) Visa refusal letters in Canada do not tell the whole story of why your visa was refused. You need to request your actual case notes. (See [here](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/atip/requests-atip.asp) or Google "CAIPS request"). There are some complications with requesting these notes outside Canada, but there are companies that help arrange the process for you for a small fee. Unfortunately the process takes a long time (about a month as far as I know).

2) Before re-applying, talk to a Canadian immigration lawyer. The lawyer will probably want to examine your previous application, maybe decide to wait for the notes (#1 above), and maybe even decide to appeal the existing application instead of submitting a new one. It is expensive, but if you reapply yourself you risk a 2nd rejection and this seriously hurts your chances of getting into Canada.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will think about it. The lesson I get from it is : Even though Canada is asking you abc just provide abcdefgh...z ;)